# m = 121, determine the possible values of $ord_m(a)$ and determine how many congruence classes mod m have each order.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

For m = 121, determine the possible values of $ord_m(a)$ and determine how many congruence classes mod m have each order.

Attempt:

The number of elements coprime to 121:
$\varphi(121)=110$

coprime to 121:{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120}

For each a, check how many elements have an order of d?

If m is prime, I can conclude the number of elements of order d is $\phi(d)$. What should I do when m(121) is not prime?

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic for odd primes $p$